# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input when using a Promise with JQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I asked a similar question the other day and decided to ask again and this time be a little more informative and supply cleaner code, and I have looked around for a solution but couldn't find anything in particular with using post or anything similar

I been trying out using jQuery Promises, and everything is fine as long as I am using a GET, but when I use a POST I start getting plagued by errors that I can't figure out.

Here's the break down...

I am inserting data to a table, the insert happens with no issues, I know because I check the database, but when it comes to the Promise being done, then it fails...
This is the initial Promise

```
function InsertCustomerPromise() {
    console.log("PROMISE CALLED");

    var newItem = CustomerToInsert();

    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../JQueryPromisesAndDeferredArea/InsertCustomer",
        dataType: "JSON",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(newItem)
    });
}
```

Here is the InsertCustomer method in my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public void InsertCustomer(Customer cust)
{
    ctx = new TDEntities();

    ctx.usp_InsertCustomer(
        cust.FirstName,
        cust.LastName
        );
}
```

The CustomerToInsert function is

```
function CustomerToInsert() {
    var cust = {
        FirstName: $('#txtFirstName').val(),
        LastName: $('#txtLastName').val()
    };
    return cust;
}
```

and this is when its done and fails

```
$('#btn').on('click', function () {
        var promised = InsertCustomerPromise();

        promised.done(function () {
            console.log("PROMISE IS DONE");
            ShowCustomerGrid();
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {            
            console.log("StatusText = " + jqXHR.statusText);
            console.log("ResponseText = " + textStatus);
            console.log("Status = " + jqXHR.status);
            console.log("Error = " + jqXHR.error.toString());
            console.log(errorThrown.toString());
        });
    });
```

The errors I am getting

> PDJS.js:12 StatusText = OK
>
> PDJS.js:13 ResponseText = parsererror
>
> PDJS.js:14 Status = 200
>
> PDJS.js:15 Error = function (){if(h){var c=h.length;!function g(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&g(c)})}(arguments),d?f=h.length:b&&(e=c,j(b))}return this}
>
> PDJS.js:16 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

One of the answers that I have seen on SO mentioned to make sure I have the correct closing braces and I believe I do.

Am I using a Promise incorrectly or is it have to do with my ajax being a POST?

Comment: Means that the server is not returning valid json

Comment: @charlietfl, I shouldnt be returning anything because the method in the controller is just a void method

Comment: Then why are you requesting json dataType? Also inspect actual request in browser dev tools network to see what if anything is actually returned

Comment: good point about dataType. Try your script without this setting.

Comment: @charlietfl, i get what you are saying, I removed the dataType and everything worked...If you want to post that and explain why the dataType was the issue then i would be more than happy to accept as the answer